# Windows 7 Driver for Cibox LW1922C

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a Cibox LW1922C monitor connected to a windows 7 machine, but I cannot find suitable drivers and I cannot seem to locate one on google.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well it's better before buying a device for your pc first check if it has a proper support

Comment: it's a work monitor I've been given.

Comment: Well there are few programs that helps you to get the driver updates and stuffs like that i use "DriverMax" you can google it

Comment: Also here is some other stuffs i found for you http://www.drivers.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that even CiboxCorp, the manufacturer, doesn't have any product pages of their monitors. There's also nothing on their ["support" page](http://www.ciboxcorp.com/support-telechargement.html).

The last thing you can try is to [contact them](http://www.ciboxcorp.com/contact.html).